# How do I add KPI targets to my cube that are at a higher grain to my fact table?

Tags: olap, ssas

I have a simple star schema with 2 dimensions; course and student.  My fact table is an enrolment on a course.  I have KPI Values set up which use data in the fact table (e.g. percentage of students that completed course).  All is working great.

I now need to add KPI Goals though that are a different grain to the fact table.  The goals are at the course level, but should also work at department level, and for whatever combination of dimension attributes are selected.  I have the numerator and denominators for the KPI Goals so want to aggregate these when there are multiple courses involved - before dividing to get the actual percentage goal.

How can I implement this?  From my understanding I should only have one fact table in my star schema.  So in that case would I perhaps store the higher grain values in the fact table?  Or would I create a dimension with these values in?  Or some alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases I would expect KPI measures to be calculated from the existing measures in your cube, so can you get away from the idea of fact table changes, and just set up KPIs as calculated members in the cube or MDX?

Your issue is complicated by the KPI granularity being different, yes...but I would just hide KPI measures when such a level of granularity was being displayed. You can implement this within the calculated measure definition too.

For example, I have used `ISLEAF()` to detect if a measure is about to be shown at the bottom level, and return blank/NULL. Or you can check the level number of any relevant dimensions.